# Integration substituion

Tags: integration, substitution

I need to use a suitable substitution to show $$\int {dx \over \sqrt{a^2+x^2}} = \text{arcsinh} \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

but I am not sure what substitution to use. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If you know that $$\cosh ^2u-\sinh^2u=1,$$ then, a suitable substitution is
$$x=a\sinh(u).$$

**Added**

Suppose $a>0$. If $x=a\sinh(u)$, then $\mathrm d x=a\cosh(u)\mathrm d u$.
Therefore,

$$\int^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\mathrm d x\underset{x=a\sinh(u)}{=}\int^{\text{arcsinh}(t)}\frac{a\cosh(u)}{\sqrt{a^2(1+\sinh^2(u))}}\mathrm d u=...$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I have tried this substituion and can't seem to get it to work. Could you help me further? thanks!

Comment: @ptsgeeg: How can't you ? Anyway, I added explications. I hope you can continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you put $a\tan(u)=x$ the integral becomes $$\int\sec\left(u\right)du$$ which is classical.